# Modifying the following methods so that I only call Nokogiri::HTML once?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

The following code scraps different sections of a site. Basically I have a few methods for each section, and then a method (`parse_details`) which merges all hashes into a single one:

```
class Parser
  def parse_details(html)
    merged_hashes = {}
    array_of_hashes = [
      self.parse_department(html),
      self.parse_super_saver(html),
    ]
    array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)

    return merged_hashes
  end

  def parse_department(file)  
    html       = file
    data       = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))
    department = data.css('#ref_2619534011')

    @department_hash = {}
    department.css('li').drop(1).each do | department |
      department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
      department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
    end 

    return @department_hash
  end 

  def parse_super_saver(file)
    html        = file
    data        = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))
    super_saver = data.css('#ref_2661623011')

    @super_saver_hash = {}
    super_saver.css('li').each do | super_saver |
      super_saver_title = super_saver.css('.refinementLink').text
      super_saver_count = super_saver.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @super_saver_hash[:super_saver] ||= {}
      @super_saver_hash[:super_saver][super_saver_title] = super_saver_count
    end 

    return @super_saver_hash
  end
```

As you can see I'm calling `Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))` more than one time.

Someone suggested me to do something like this:

```
  def self.parse(html)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML html 
    self.parse_details(doc) unless doc.nil?
  end
```

So I call `Nokogiri::HTML` only once.

But I'm stuck, for instance I have no idea what to do with parts like `department = data.css('#ref_2619534011')` should they go in the new `parse` method or not? I'm also confused about what to do with the `html` and `file` argument. After having the new `parse` method, should I leave them there or remove them?

Any suggestions of how I can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Simple conversion:

```ruby
class Parser
  def initialize(url)
    @data = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
  end
  def parse_details()
    {}.tap do |merged_hashes|
      array_of_hashes = [
        parse_department(),
        parse_super_saver(),
      ]
      array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)
    end
  end

  def parse_department()  
    department = @data.css('#ref_2619534011')

    @department_hash = {}
    department.css('li').drop(1).each do | department |
      department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
      department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
    end 
    @department_hash
  end 

  def parse_super_saver()
    super_saver = @data.css('#ref_2661623011')

    @super_saver_hash = {}
    super_saver.css('li').each do | super_saver |
      super_saver_title = super_saver.css('.refinementLink').text
      super_saver_count = super_saver.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @super_saver_hash[:super_saver] ||= {}
      @super_saver_hash[:super_saver][super_saver_title] = super_saver_count
    end 
    @super_saver_hash
  end
end
```

If you don't actually need `@department_hash` and `@super_saver_hash` as instance variables, you might choose to convert them to the `tap` style I used in `parse_details`.

If you don't actually need this to be a class at all, but just a collection of methods, then consider instead:

```ruby
module Parser
  def self.parse_details(url)
    data = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
    {}.tap do |merged_hashes|
      array_of_hashes = [
        parse_department(data),
        parse_super_saver(data),
      ]
      array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)
    end
  end

  def self.parse_department(data)
    {}.tap do |department_hash|
      data.css('#ref_2619534011 li').drop(1).each do | department |
        department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
        department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
        department_hash[:department] ||= {}
        department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
        department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
      end
    end
  end 

  def self.parse_super_saver(data)    
    {}.tap do |super_saver_hash|
      data.css('#ref_2661623011 li').each do |super_saver|
        super_saver_title = super_saver.css('.refinementLink').text
        super_saver_count = super_saver.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
        super_saver_hash[:super_saver] ||= {}
        super_saver_hash[:super_saver][super_saver_title] = super_saver_count
      end 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing the code with something like this: `let(:department_hash) { Parser.new.parse html_pet_supplies }` And I'm getting an error like: `Failure/Error: let(:department_hash) { Parser.new.parse html_pet_supplies }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./parser.rb:4:in `initialize'
     # ./parser_spec.rb:24:in `new'` What could be the cause?

Comment: "Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" means "you're calling a method that's supposed to be given 1 argument, and you're giving it 0". Specifically, you should be calling `Parser.new(url)` if you're using my top code, or `Parser.parse_details( url )` if you're using the second.